# How find set $f(\Bbb R^3)$ for $f(x, y ,z)= e^{i(x+y+z)} + e^{i(x-y-z)}+ e^{i(-x+ y-z)}+ e^{i(-x-y+ z)}$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Let $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb C$ such that $f(x, y ,z)= e^{i(x+y+z)} + e^{i(x-y-z)}+ e^{i(-x+ y-z)}+ e^{i(-x-y+ z)}$. 
How can one find the set $f(\Bbb R^3)$?

Comment: Well it's all inside the disc about $z=0$ of radius $4$.  Not sure it's onto that disc though...

Comment: Try to simplify the expression. I get $4\cos x\cos y\cos z-4i\sin x\sin y\sin z$...

Comment: I don't know why, but the range seems to be the non-convex region $\{ u+iv \in \mathbb{C} :  (u^2+v^2-16)^3 + 16 \cdot 27u^2 v^2 \leq 0 \} $